# FabricJS loadSVGFromURL() not working at localhost

Tags: svg, localhost, fabricjs

I know this problem is somewhat related to the file origin. When I put up a fiddle from a secure URL, it doesn't work (https://jsfiddle.net/fccarminati/c7f53g9j/). However, if I access it from non-secure URL it does (http://jsfiddle.net/fccarminati/c7f53g9j/).

Now when trying to make this work locally, I put up an Apache server to host my files. It doesn't give me a cross-origin error at the console, but it does not import the svg correctly either.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btnAddSVG" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Add SVG</button>
    <canvas width="800" height="600" id="c"></canvas>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/fabric.js"></script>
    <script src="js/test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
 var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

 //add sticker
$('#btnAddSVG').on('click', function(){

    fabric.loadSVGFromURL('http://localhost:81/appcoperia/stickers/1.svg', function(objects) { 
        var group = new fabric.PathGroup(objects, { 
            left: 100, 
            top: 100, 
            width: 150, 
            height: 150 
        });

        canvas.add(group); 
        canvas.renderAll(); 

    }); 

});
```

**Does anyone know what other problems should I look into?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have enough reputation to comment, so...

> When I put up a fiddle from a secure URL, it doesn't work (https://jsfiddle.net/fccarminati/c7f53g9j/)

Your SVG file url must use HTTPS to. So, try to change to `https://fabricjs.com/assets/1.svg` in your js source file. It maybe not work on first time. Also, you have to try [open the url on new tab of your browser](https://fabricjs.com/assets/1.svg) and accept the security warnings.

> "Now when trying to make this work locally, ..."

<strike>I will try to run it locally and update this answer. (But, just in case, its not a "PORT 81" problem, right? Your apache is running at :81?)</strike>

---

[UPDATE]
Your code LGTM. I did this (and works):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btnAddSVG" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Add SVG</button>
    <canvas width="800" height="600" id="c"></canvas>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.3/fabric.min.js" integrity="sha256-BeLYOR7hF1X4xXnJJkOvwf2nNkZK9Fe2OJgoa2/maqA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
        //add sticker
        $('#btnAddSVG').on('click', function(){

            fabric.loadSVGFromURL('http://0.0.0.0:8000/1.svg', function(objects) { 
                var group = new fabric.PathGroup(objects, { 
                    left: 100, 
                    top: 100, 
                    width: 150, 
                    height: 150 
                });

                canvas.add(group); 
                canvas.renderAll(); 

            }); 

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Atention to the URL / file path. In my case, my server was running at localhost:8000, and the SVG was at the same folder of the html file.

Comment: Turns out it was not a file origin problem. It was the fabricJS import. I used your cdnjs link and it worked. I downloaded the file from fabricjs website, but it seems there is a problem with it. I'll look into it. Thank you!!